# Does using the 'ant' tag in an ant script start a seperate JVM?

Tags: ant

Does using the 'ant' tag in an ant script start a seperate JVM?

My code is like:

```
<target name="run" description="base tests">
       <ant dir="suite1"/>
       <ant dir="suite2"/>
       <ant dir="suite3"/>
</target
```

From ANT manual, it says that if we use 'ant' inside target tag, it is not part of same build file, but when I monitor the Java process, only one Java process runs on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs as a separate project within the same JVM